# How to pass user and pwd in a more secure way on HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, httpsurlconnection

I`m passing the user credential login to our internal HTTPs service using just a basic authorization, as you can see in the code below. But this piece of code is being rejected by our security team so I must change it asap. Do you know any other form that I could use to perform this login activity in a more secure way?

```
encodedAuthString = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((userName + ":" + pass).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

http_connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthString);

HttpsURLConnection http_connection = (HttpsURLConnection) clientURL.openConnection();
```

Comment: if the username and password is only used for internal use, you could ask the security team to encode `username + ":" pass` with their own secret. Store the encoded secret as an environment variable and reference it in your code. I think the security concern here is referencing the actual username and password.

Comment: As your code demonstrates, Basic Auth sends a plaintext username and password _encoded_ in Base64. Some other more secure options are JWT and OAuth. Without knowing _why_ your security team considers this an issue (e.g. because the user/pass are cleartext? Because you're using a user account instead of a service account for an internal API? Because no hashing is being done?), it's hard to guess at what a more appropriate solution would be for your situation.